# clubs -> tournaments?

Tags: tournament, clubs

I live in Maharashtra, India, and can't find any tournaments (that don't take a lot of entry fee) to participate in, and I really want to. There are some clubs near me, though. What I wanted to ask is that will chess clubs notify me regularly about tournaments (I want to participate in ANY tournament I can, that doesn't cost TOO much in entry fee, and is not TOO far from me) that I can participate in?

Comment: Unfortunately tournaments charge high fees so the sponsors can make money and also offer big prizes to attract more high rated players which the lower rated people want to play against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, chess clubs usually inform their players about tournaments organized in the vicinity. Anyway, you can ask any particular club about its policy before joining it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even if the club does not formally inform you of tournaments, you would most likely learn about them by talking to other players.

Also most clubs would organize club only tournaments and other small local tournaments that are difficult to learn about from the internet. Besides, you might be able to participate in team league competitions.